# PHP check if Array is Empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Multi-Dimensional Array as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [featured] => Yes
            [job_code] => WT3
            [title] => Senior Test Engineer - dB Testing
            [no_of_pos] => 5
            [experience] => 3 to 5 years
            [job_desc] => Work with Dev counterparts to understand the implementation details.
Adhere to all quality standards from QA perspective.
Able to independently come up with test cases based on the analysis of functionality.
Test planning and Test Design (Creation of Test scenarios/Test Cases)
Preparation of Test environment
Execution of Test cases
Identification, reporting and tracking of defects
            [skillsets] => Should be experienced in testing on Mac OS X
Should be familiar with terms such as plist, starutp options on Mac, OS versions
Should be familiar with Terminal and Console on Mac OS X
Should be familiar with Apple Script Editor or Automator
Should be able to troubleshoot basic boot issues on Mac
            [keywords] => Black Box testing, Web Testing, e-Commerce, SQL queries/database testing
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [featured] => No
            [job_code] => MNX-7A
            [title] => Test Engineer - Mac OS X
            [no_of_pos] => 1
            [experience] => 3 to 5 years
            [job_desc] => Should be excellent in Black Box Test Case Design
Should be able to understand business requirements and develop relevant scenarios and test cases 
Good knowledge on the SDLC / STLC
Preparation of Test environment
Execution of Test cases
Identification, reporting and tracking of defects
            [skillsets] => Should be experienced in testing on Mac OS X
Should be familiar with terms such as plist, starutp options on Mac, OS versions
Should be familiar with Terminal and Console on Mac OS X
Should be familiar with Apple Script Editor or Automator
Should be able to troubleshoot basic boot issues on Mac
            [keywords] => Black Box Testing, Mac OS X
        )

)
```

I want to iterate thru the array and make sure all the fields have a value and not empty.

Which is the best way to do it ?

Comment: does that check all keys and values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<?php

$data=array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'featured' => 'Yes',
            'job_code' => 'WT3',
            'title' => 'Senior Test Engineer - dB Testing',
            'no_of_pos' => '5',
            'experience' => '3 to 5 years',
            'job_desc' => 'Work with Dev counterparts to understand the implementation details.
Adhere to all quality standards from QA perspective.
Able to independently come up with test cases based on the analysis of functionality.
Test planning and Test Design (Creation of Test scenarios/Test Cases)
Preparation of Test environment
Execution of Test cases
Identification, reporting and tracking of defects
            [skillsets] => Should be experienced in testing on Mac OS X
Should be familiar with terms such as plist, starutp options on Mac, OS versions
Should be familiar with Terminal and Console on Mac OS X
Should be familiar with Apple Script Editor or Automator
Should be able to troubleshoot basic boot issues on Mac',
            'keywords' => 'Black Box testing, Web Testing, e-Commerce, SQL queries/database testing'
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            'featured' => 'No',
            'job_code' => 'MNX-7A',
            'title' => 'Test Engineer - Mac OS X',
            'no_of_pos' => '1',
            'experience' => '3 to 5 years',
            'job_desc' => 'Should be excellent in Black Box Test Case Design
Should be able to understand business requirements and develop relevant scenarios and test cases 
Good knowledge on the SDLC / STLC
Preparation of Test environment
Execution of Test cases
Identification, reporting and tracking of defects',
            'skillsets' => 'Should be experienced in testing on Mac OS X
Should be familiar with terms such as plist, starutp options on Mac, OS versions
Should be familiar with Terminal and Console on Mac OS X
Should be familiar with Apple Script Editor or Automator
Should be able to troubleshoot basic boot issues on Mac',
            'keywords' => 'Black Box Testing, Mac OS X'
        )

);

function anyEmpty($array) {
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        if (!is_array($arr)) {
            if (empty($arr)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (anyEmpty($arr)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(anyEmpty($data));

?>
```

In this example, all fields are set, so it will echo `bool(false)`. However, if I change one of the fields to `''` it will return true.

Example:

```
<?php

$data=array
(
    0=>array(
        0=>"hello",
        1=>array(
            0=>"world"
        ),
        2=>array(
            0=>"my name",
            array(
                0=>""
            )
        )
    )
);

function anyEmpty($array) {
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        if (!is_array($arr)) {
            if (empty($arr)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (anyEmpty($arr)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(anyEmpty($data));

?>
```

This now returns `bool(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a simple loop is always mush faster.

```
function yourFunction($array, $key, $val) {
    foreach ($array as $item)
        if (isset($item[$key])
          // do what you intend to here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below one. It referenced to php.net [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#92308)

```
function is_multiArrayEmpty($multiarray) { 
        if(is_array($multiarray) and !empty($multiarray)){ 
            $tmp = array_shift($multiarray); 
                if(!is_multiArrayEmpty($multiarray) or !is_multiArrayEmpty($tmp)){ 
                    return false; 
                } 
                return true; 
        } 
        if(empty($multiarray)){ 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    }
```